# R package check, error cannot find package when running examples

Tags: r, package

I am writing a package called `BiProbitPartial`. When I run `devtools::check()` I get an error when I get to "checking examples ..." for both 'i386' and 'x64'. A snippet of the error is

```
library('BiProbitPartial')
```

> Error in library("BiProbitPartial") :     there is no package called
>   'BiProbitPartial'   Execution halted

Which makes it sound like package cannot find itself.

I am running windows 10 with [r](/questions/tagged/r) 3.5.2, [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) 1.1.463, `devtools` 2.0.1.

I am thinking it's a library path problem. I am not sure how to properly diagnose it. Running `.libPaths()` gets me

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/mguggisb/Documents/R/win-library/3.5"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/library"
```

The full error output is

> - checking examples ...
>     ** running examples for arch 'i386' ... ERROR   Running examples in 'BiProbitPartial-Ex.R' failed   The error occurred in:
>
> R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo"   Copyright (C) 2018
>   The R Foundation for Statistical Computing   Platform:
>   i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
>
> R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.   You are
>   welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.   Type
>   'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
>
> Natural language support but running in an English locale
>
> R is a collaborative project with many contributors.   Type
>   'contributors()' for more information and   'citation()' on how to
>   cite R or R packages in publications.
>
> Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
>   'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.   Type 'q()' to
>   quit R.
>
> > pkgname <- "BiProbitPartial"
> >     source(file.path(R.home("share"), "R", "examples-header.R"))
> >     options(warn = 1)
> >     options(pager = "console")
> >     base::assign(".ExTimings", "BiProbitPartial-Ex.timings", pos =     'CheckExEnv')
> >     base::cat("name\tuser\tsystem\telapsed\n", file=base::get(".ExTimings", pos = 'CheckExEnv'))
> >     base::assign(".format_ptime",
> >     + function(x) {
> >     +   if(!is.na(x[4L])) x[1L] <- x[1L] + x[4L]
> >     +   if(!is.na(x[5L])) x[2L] <- x[2L] + x[5L]
> >     +   options(OutDec = '.')
> >     +   format(x[1L:3L], digits = 7L)
> >     + },
> >     + pos = 'CheckExEnv')
> >
> > #### *
> >
> > library('BiProbitPartial')   Error in library("BiProbitPartial") :      there is no package called 'BiProbitPartial'   Execution halted
> >     ** running examples for arch 'x64' ... ERROR   Running examples in 'BiProbitPartial-Ex.R' failed   The error occurred in:
>
> R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo" Copyright (C) 2018
>   The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
>   x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. You are
>   welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. Type 'license()'
>   or 'licence()' for distribution details.
>
> Natural language support but running in an English locale
>
> R is a collaborative project with many contributors. Type
>   'contributors()' for more information and 'citation()' on how to cite
>   R or R packages in publications.
>
> Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
>   'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help. Type 'q()' to
>   quit R.
>
> > pkgname <- "BiProbitPartial"
> >     source(file.path(R.home("share"), "R", "examples-header.R"))
> >     options(warn = 1)
> >     options(pager = "console")
> >     base::assign(".ExTimings", "BiProbitPartial-Ex.timings", pos = 'CheckExEnv')
> >     base::cat("name\tuser\tsystem\telapsed\n", file=base::get(".ExTimings", pos = 'CheckExEnv'))
> >     base::assign(".format_ptime",
> >     + function(x) {
> >     +   if(!is.na(x[4L])) x[1L] <- x[1L] + x[4L]
> >     +   if(!is.na(x[5L])) x[2L] <- x[2L] + x[5L]
> >     +   options(OutDec = '.')
> >     +   format(x[1L:3L], digits = 7L)
> >     + },
> >     + pos = 'CheckExEnv')
> >
> > #### *
> >
> > library('BiProbitPartial') Error in library("BiProbitPartial") :    there is no package called 'BiProbitPartial' Execution halted
> >     * DONE Status: 2 ERRORs

Comment: Are you doing `library("BiProbitPartial")` in your examples? You should not.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I am not

Comment: @mike have you solved this issue? I'm experiencing similar problems and suspect that `devtools` 2.0.1 might be causing problems here. Have you tried to run same tests with an updated version?

Comment: @KasiaKulma I don't remember exactly.  I think it was remedied by adding `#'@aliases BiProbitPartial-package` followed by `"_PACKAGE"` at the end of my R script. Let me know if that does the trick.

Comment: Thanks, @mike that's a great start. Which R script did you add it to?

Comment: @KasiaKulma I added it to the script that contained the function that had the same name as my package. They were both named "BiProbitPartial"

Comment: ahh, ok, I see why this would create a problem that aliases would solve. Unfortunately, something else must be causing my issues.. thanks for your help, anyway!

Comment: I get the same issue using roxygen2 7.1.0 and devtools 2.2.2. Code is


`> pkgname <- "foo.bar"
[...]
  > library('foo.bar')

  Error in library("foo.bar") : 

    there is no package called 'foo.bar'`

I do not call the package in the examples.